# Start Python from Windows PowerShell

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I know this looks like a question answered thousands of time, but none of the traditional answers concerning the environment PATH are working.

I want to run the following in Windows 7, in Powershell:

```
python mycode.py
```

However, Powershell returns an error, stating that `python not recognized as an applet, function, application,...`

These are my path variables:

Users variables:

```
PATH 
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;
C:\Python27;
C:\Python27\DLLs;
C:\Python27\Scripts;
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\vtk;
C:\Python27\gnuplot\binary;
C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\SciTE-3.3.2-3;
C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\console;
C:\MinGW32-xy\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\swig;
C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\gettext\bin

PATHEXT 
.PY;.PYW

PYTHON_INCLUDE 
C:\Python27\include

PYTHON_LIB 
C:\Python27\libs\python27.lib
```

and System variables:

```
PATH
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;
C:\Python27;
C:\Python27\DLLs;
C:\Python27\Scripts;
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\vtk;
C:\Python27\gnuplot\binary;
C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\SciTE-3.3.2-3;
C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\console;
C:\MinGW32-xy\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\swig;
C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\gettext\bin;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS
```

I tried the following:

```
$env:Path = $env:Path + ";C:\Python27\"
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User")
```

without success. (I tried starting a new Powershell session, of course, and even tried to reboot my PC)

Could it be that PowerShell doesn't properly read the path variable, or I don't have some permission? I am lost, especially knowing that this work fine on another Windows 7 install. I note that typing:

```
python.exe
```

...opens a Python terminal as expected.

Edit : Ok I tried the following test.py code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print "Hello"
input()

python.exe test.py
```

open a new terminal with "Hello" in it and wait for my input
but I don't want that, I expect the normal behaviour, with "Hello" printed in PowerShell, error message in PowerShell and so on.

Edit2 : I noticed that the "Path" variable given in PowerShell by:
    Get-ChildItem Env

Is not equal to the one in the W7 options "System -> Advanced System settings -> Environment variable" . it was only :

```
;C:\Python27
```

Like if my previous command line 
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27")
just wrote in it. Fixing this didn't solve my problem either.

Comment: Have you tried "python.exe yourcode.py" ? If you say python.exe opens the pythonshell, this should work

Comment: Try invoking python from cmd.exe.  That will tell you if it is a path problem (most likely) or something specific to PowerShell.  FWIW I know of no issues with PowerShell's use of the PATH env var.

Comment: @Keith from cmd.exe i get : "'python' is not recognized as a internal or external command..."

Comment: @Loris python.exe mycode.py open an python terminal that dies immediately. The code is not executed because 1) It's way too quick 2) It should open a matplotlib figure that need to be close on my other install in order to exit the script.

Comment: @fmollica are you really complaining about code executing too quick? If it dies immediately it more sounds like an fault in your code.

Comment: @Loris This very same code work fine on another machine, but why not, it could be wrong. However it's not even my point. I expect the verbatim of my code to be print in PowerShell. I expect `code`python test.py`code` to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Running any executable using Powershell (not just Python.exe) is possible using multiple approaches, but what has worked best for me is `iex`.

The basic steps I follow are:

- Find the path to executable
- Construct command string
- Run `iex` on it. Use `&` to account for spaces in file paths.

To find the executable, I generally use `get-command`. This searches PATH:

```
    if (get-command curl.exe) {
        $exePath = "curl.exe"
    }

    $Cmd = '"'+ $exePath + '"' + ' args'
    iex "& $curlCmd"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it is a bit over my head. What is the purpose of that ?

Comment: The point is, that you can't type `python test.py` and expect that to work. (or in general, `someExe file.exe` doesn't always work on a Powershell prompt). `iex` makes it more reliable. was that clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Adding "C\Python27" in "System -> Advanced System settings -> Environment variable" to the system variables solved my issue. For me it was only in user variables.